# slideToggle Drop down Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I need some help with Jquery please.

I've got this string of code which triggers my drop-down menu to be displayed/hidden (visibility):

```
// toggle the menu items' visiblity
      .find('h2')
         .bind('click focus', function(){
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('expanded')
         });
```

*Code taken from:* http://filamentgroup.com/examples/rwd-nav-patterns/

However, I want to be able to toggle it using Jquery (want the smooth transition).

**QUESTION:**

How can I adapt this code to get the slideToggle to work?

I've tried replacing 'toggleClass' with 'slideToggle', which in a way works, but instead toggles my menu up, thus hiding 'h2'.

**JSFiddle link: Please resize the window slightly for @Media Query to kick-in.
Red box (top right corner) represents the drop down menu.**

### http://jsfiddle.net/87G6a/

All comments/answers are much appreciated and will be voted up.

Thank you.

Comment: setup a fiddle with an attempt. This is a relatively easy task, but we can't help unless we see your code.

Comment: @DavidAguirre Thanks for the suggestion. I've uploaded a link to a stripped down version of my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/defmetalhead/2ezsP/

```
$('.mainMenu').children('li').on('click', function() {
   $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow'); 
});
```

Everything in that code can be done a different(better) way. However, check this updated fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/defmetalhead/87G6a/2/

```
 .find('h2')
    .bind('click focus', function () {
    $('ul').slideToggle('slow');
  });
```

BE a bit more specfic as to what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the example. But is there a way to adapt my current code to get it to work, without drastically altering the html navigation structure? I've been trying but with no luck.

Comment: Make the width of the result window smaller. Resize it down. "h2" element should appear as a red box in top right corner. You can click it to display/hide the menu li's.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('nav ul li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.sub-menu li').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: While this code may be an answer to the problem us would be better if you added an explanation of what the codes does and how it answers the question.